# Connect MS Planner to MS Project

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-project, microsoft-planner

I want to connect MS Planner with MS Project. However when I click the "Planner" button on the "Tasks" tab. Then the option to connect with existing planner is frozen. (screen in polish bellow)

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L7M2.png)

What am I doing wrong? Why cannot connect with planner published in office 365 website?

Possibly there are some alternative methods to synchronize planner with project?

Comment: Could you translate the error message into English to help me better analyze the issue?

Comment: It is not an error per se. What this screen is showing is only that the button "connect with existing plan from planner program" is actually frozen and I have no idea why is that.